# Would Sandanam have been evil if it hadn't been for Rolex?

Tags: vikram

In the movie *Vikram*, is Sandanam himself a drug lord because of Rolex, or is it because he himself thinks he wants to be powerful? Because in the movie Sandanam, repeatedly references Rolex and that he is fearful that Rolex will destroy his family. So would he have been evil if it hadn't been for Rolex?

Answer (score 0):

Vikram movie climax shows how deadly Rolex was. He wanted his goons to address him as "Sir".  His way of making them get to know itself showed his power and his temper.  Sandhanam could have been powerful if he had his own supply of drugs, but he must be able to face Rolex to do so. This made Sandanam look weak when he was to be stronger.  His character was less powerful in the presence of a drug lord who looked dangerous.
I feel Sandhanam would have been the drug lord within a small region if not for Rolex.  Whereas Rolex controlled a large area and had many goons and small thugs under him.  Rolex is more powerful and dangerous than Sandhanam.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your answer.  You say "Sandhanam would have been the drug lord within a small region if not for Rolex" but Sandhanam _is_ a drug lord; do you mean he _still_ would have been a drug lord _without_ Rolex?  That does answer the question, but what is the evidence for that?

Comment: He wouldnt have been a better druglord , the evidence was that he was so vulnerable that Amar planned to bring down his place with dynamites and executed it in his presence , he was so devastated to see his own kingdom fall down easily and he did save his people,but lost his place so easily.